# How to find the limit of the following question when x approaches 0 from positive side?

Tags: calculus

\begin{equation}
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}(\sin 2 x)^{\tan 2 x}
\end{equation}

Comment: Write it as $$e^{\ln((\sin 2x)^{\tan 2x})}$$

Comment: I still don't get it, could you explain more?

Comment: See the answers below. You transform $0^0$ into a ratio that you can solve with l'Hopital

Comment: Got it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $u = x$:

$$L = \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\sin(2x)^{\tan(2x)} = \lim_{u\to 0^{+}}\sin(u)^{\tan(u)}$$

Then, we have, noting that $\sin(u)^{\tan(u)} > 0$ for $u > 0$:

$$\ln(L) = \ln\big(\lim_{u\to 0^{+}}\sin(u)^{\tan(u)}\big) =\lim_{u\to 0^{+}}\ln(\sin(u)^{\tan(u)}) =\lim_{u\to 0^{+}}\frac{\ln(\sin(u))}{\cot(u)}$$

Using l'Hopital:

$$\ln(L) = \lim_{u\to 0^{+}}\frac{\frac{d}{du}\ln(\sin(u))}{\frac{d}{du}\cot(u)} = \lim_{u\to 0^{+}}\frac{\cot(u)}{-\csc^{2}(u)} = \lim_{u\to 0^{+}}-\cos(u)\sin(u) = 0$$

Thus, $L = e^{0} = \boxed{1}$

You can also solve this by noting that $\sin(u)\approx \tan(u)\approx u$ for $u\approx 0$, and from there finding $\displaystyle\lim_{u\to 0^{+}}u^{u} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Around $0^+$, $\sin(2x)>0$, therefore we can write
$$ \sin(2x)^{\tan(2x)}=\exp(\tan(2x)\log\sin(2x)) $$
But $\log\sin(2x)=\log\left(2x+o(x^2)\right)=\log(2x)+\log(1+o(x))=\log(2x)+o(x)=\log(2x)+o(\log x)$, therefore $\log(\sin(2x))\sim\log(2x)$. Moreover, $\tan(2x)\sim 2x$ thus $\tan(2x)\log\sin(2x)\sim2x\log(2x)\underset{x\rightarrow 0^+}\longrightarrow 0$ and finally, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\sin(2x)^{\tan(2x)}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use the standard limit $\lim_{t\to 0^+}t^t=1$ which can be proved quickly by taking the logarithm and using L'Hospital.

Now, just substituting $t=\sin 2x$ you get

$$(\sin 2 x)^{\tan 2 x}\stackrel{t=\sin 2x}{=} \left(t^t\right)^{\frac 1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}}\stackrel{t\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow}1^1 = 1$$